# Javascript dropdown menu stay open onced clicked

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and I have found a script that lets me create a dropdown menu onclick, however I would like the menu to stay open when clicking on the other list items from the dropdown menu. Right now each time I click on a different item from my menu the menu collapse. Not to sure what codes too share so I've shared my javascript. Any help is appreciated Thanks!!

```
ddaccordion.init({
    headerclass: "submenuheader", 
    contentclass: "submenu", 
    revealtype: "click", 
    collapseprev: true, 
    defaultexpanded: [], 
    onemustopen: false, 
    animatedefault: false,
    persiststate: true, 
    toggleclass: ["", ""], 
    animatespeed: "fast",   
})
```

Comment: what's the plugin are you using?

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ddaccordionmenu.htm) script?

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
  collapseprev: false,
```

it may work for you.

Comment: Yes I'm using that script, and I've tried the collapse: false but the pages always loads the menu as open and when i try to click it to close doesn't work :/

Comment: this is done at the time of initialization as you have wrote in ddaccordion.init you can also use code in other event according your requirement

Comment: I'm sure that works and i appreciate the help but I don;t really know where to go from there because I'm such a noob at scripting :o